# MySQL не реагирует на условие

Tags: php, запрос, sql

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notifications` WHERE `npoints` > 0 AND `to` = 1 OR `from` = 1");
return mysql_num_rows($query);
```

не реагирует на `npoints > 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подозреваю что вы хотели так:

```
SELECT * FROM `notifications` WHERE `npoints` > 0 AND (`to` = 1 OR `from` = 1)
```

Обратите внимание, я добавил скобки в условие!

Comment: Черт, опередили))

Comment: Из своего ответа добавлю, что у AND выше приоритет, поэтому группируется не так, как надо @ModaL

Comment: @Павел Вершинин, мерси :)